# What do you mean by Rebalancing?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

In the **equal distribution strategy** section on this [page](https://www.sectorspdr.com/sectorspdr/investment-strategy), there is a mentioning of **rebalancing**. What do you mean by **rebalancing**? Does it happen at the beginning of the quarter or at the end of the quarter?

Comment: Some say you best rebalance once a year, only, because you may have to pay taxes when you hold shares shorter than a year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An Equal Sector Strategy is a strategy that delivers exposure to the US Large Cap Equity market by investing equal proportions in each of the 11 Select Sector SPDRs

Just in case you wondered why 9.09%:

`1/11 = 9.09%`

> This strategy delivers moderate, yet meaningful exposure to every sector of the market. As a result, investors have the opportunity not only to participate in a sector rally wherever it may occur, but also to minimize the negative impact of a crash in any individual sector by rebalancing back to equal weight (9.09% in each sector) quarterly.

Let say that your tech stocks boom in 2021Q3, and at the end they are 12.5% of your portfolio.  Therefore, some/all of the other 10 portfolio sectors are less than 9.09% of your total portfolio.  Thus, your total portfolio is **out of balance**.

Now you should see what rebalance means: sell some tech shares, and use that money to buy shares in the other sectors so that you're back *in balance* (9.09% per sector).

Naturally, this is a simplified example. In the real world, with 11 sectors, it'll get more complicated.  (Note that I would *not* get obsessed about having *exactly 9.09%* in each sector, since share prices won't always allow it.)

> Does it happen at the beginning of the quarter or at the end of the quarter?

**The day after** EOQ (End of Quarter) is the BOQ (Beginning of Quarter).  It honestly doesn't make any difference (except at EOY -- End of Year -- when you might need to sell before EOY for tax purposes).

Comment: perfect answer, now I don't need to write anything (so thanks for that)

Answer (score 3):

When you select an *Asset Allocation*, you are choosing what percentage of your assets go into specific "buckets" (e.g. Cash, High Yield Bonds, Safe Bonds, Large-Cap Stocks, Mid-Cap, Global, Domestic, etc.) Whatever your preferred percentages are, after even just 1 day they will be different than what you elected. Over time the difference can become significant enough that you may wish to **rebalance** and move money from buckets that are too full, into other buckets that are lacking, to get back to your original preferred percentages.

There is no rule for *when* you should rebalance; you can do it as often as you want (within reason). Quarterly, semi-annual, and even annually are all possible frequencies. Some people never rebalance at all.

**Suggestion**: if you are a passive investor, rebalancing on an automated schedule is probably best. Once you try to time the market by rebalancing based on certain indicators, you introduce an element of risk that you may not be comfortable with.